# Visual studio Forms not working in production

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a basic form built in .net 6. It was a very rough and ready bit of code to do a one or check on some data.

It populates a datatable from SQL thid data includes file paths. (32k rows)

It then loops through all the the rows of the data table using a foreach loop.

The loops check to see if the directory from the row exists. If it does, it then counts the files in the folder. (approx. 120 files per folder)

It then does some checks up dates a valid or invalid counter. If invalid it then adds a row to another datatable that is export to an excel document once the foreach loop is complete

This all works perfectly in visual studio using F5.
If I run it via other method. Ctrl + f5, from the bin folder or publish. It works to check about 900+ folders (50,000) files and the just hangs.

What is going on??

I know its something to to with the files as if I strip the Foreach down to just looping through the data table it all works, but as soon as I add the directory.exists it hangs several seconds in.

```
public void CheckFolder()
        {
            int matched = 0;
            int notmatched = 0;
            lb_mismatchCount.Text = notmatched.ToString();

            lb_MatchedCount.Text = matched.ToString();

            lb_mismatchCount.Visible = true;
            lb_MatchedCount.Visible = true;
            lbTotalPhotos.Text = null;
            lbTotalPhotos.Visible = true;
            try
            {




                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                   
                    if (Directory.Exists($@"My directory path here{row[3].ToString()}"))
                    {

                        int fileCount =  GetFileCount($@"My directory path here{row[3].ToString()}", false);

                        totalfiles = totalfiles + fileCount;
                        lbTotalPhotos.Text = totalfiles.ToString("N0");

                        lbTotalPhotos.Refresh();

                        if (fileCount / 2 == Convert.ToInt32(row[4].ToString()))
                        {


                            matched++;
                            lb_MatchedCount.Text = matched.ToString("N0");
                            lb_MatchedCount.Refresh();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            DataRow newRow = output.NewRow();
                            newRow[0] = row[0].ToString();
                            newRow[1] = row[2].ToString();
                            output.Rows.Add(newRow);

                            notmatched++;
                            lb_mismatchCount.Text = notmatched.ToString("N0");
                            lb_mismatchCount.Refresh();
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        notmatched++;
                        lb_mismatchCount.Text = notmatched.ToString("N0");
                        lb_mismatchCount.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
          


        }
```

If I change the foreachloop to the below it still hangs.

```
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                   
                    if (Directory.Exists($@"My directory path here{row[3].ToString()}"))
                    {}
                }
```

Comment: It's probably swamping the UI. You might have to change the code to update the UI in batches, rather than trying to update (and `Refresh()`) for each item. In particular, `output.Rows.Add(newRow);` is likely causing issues. If you can batch the data and call `output.Rows.AddRange(...)` it should be much more performant.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Hi that was my first thought. But I stripped down the foreach loop so it was just the   if (Directory.Exists($@"My directory path here{row[3].ToString()}")) statment with nothing inside it and didnt update the UI at all . It still hung

Comment: I do not necessarily see anything that would cause the freeze, however, are you ware that all the code that sets the labels text… is really not useful. The labels will not update until the code exits `CheckFolder`. So you will only see the labels results from the last iteration of the loop. Are you expecting this?

Comment: @johnG. Hi yeah the code was cobbled together, so they are left over from when the foreach loop was more basic just to prove the concept worked.  With a run via F5 the  form works as expected label text and all.